# WPF TreeViewItem Style individual borders

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem, xaml-resources

I need to create 3 styles for the items in a TreeView:

Style1 should show a border at the top of the item (full line, not only this item's content width)

Style2 should have no border, but a Red background (this is done already)

Style3 should show a border at the bottom of the item

The styles will be assigned in code behind according to some situation.

How do I define the borders in these styles?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different DataTemplates in one TreeView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568597/different-datatemplates-in-one-treeview)

Comment: @ChrisW. Not at all, I need to work with the top/bottom borders. That's my question.

Comment: Howdy @igorjrr , what do you think provides those borders? There's an `ItemsPresenter` in the [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that displays your Item Itemplate(s) via DataTemplate(s) so by changing your Item templates and exposing places to do your requirements and toggle them accordingly, then you'll get your required result.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, Chris. But I don't know exactly what property I should change to draw only the top or the bottom border. Any further help?

Comment: You would specify an ItemTemplate with for example a `Border` control in it where you could do something like `<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="0,1"/>` which in example would display a green line on just the top and bottom of that Border within your template. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @ChrisW. So BorderThickness it is! Thank you! :)